# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li' in ngFor Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I saw another question about the same problem, but I don't know why I get this error.
The odd thing here is that I did  another component that returns a array and works fine, now I've created this new one but it doesn't work.

**Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'**

this is my component SubscriptionCustumerComponent:

```
    public subscriptions:Subscription[];

constructor(private subscriptionService:CustumerSubscriptionService){} 

ngOnInit(): void {

        this.subscriptionService.getsubscriptionbyID(this.userid)
        .subscribe(res=>this.subscriptions=res,
            error=> this.errorMessage);
    
}
```

the page:

```
    <ul  class="nav">
    <li *ngFor="let data of subscriptions" >
        <div class="card">
             <img src="{{data.image}}" style="width:100%;height:250px;">
            <h1>{{data.name}}</h1>
          </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the SubscriptionModule:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CustumerSubscriptionService } from "./service/subscription.service";
import { CustumerSubscriptionAppComponent } from "./subscription.app.component";
import { CustumerSubscriptioRoutingModule } from "./subscription.route";

@NgModule({

    declarations:[
        CustumerSubscriptionAppComponent
    ],
    imports:[
        CommonModule,
        CustumerSubscriptioRoutingModule
        
    ],
    providers:[
        CustumerSubscriptionService
    ]
})

export class CustumerSubscriptionModule{}
```

and the main Module AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NavegacaoModule,
    NgbModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [httpInterceptorProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried to import BrowserModule in your SubscriptionModule ? https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolved-cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div/#.YCsJLWhKiUk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell your component is called `SubscriptionCustomerComponent`, however it is not declared in the `SubscriptionModule`. Instead, we have `CustomerSubscriptionAppComponent`.

This could be an issue because all other things (including browser module and common module) seem to be correct.

Comment: yeah this was a error, thx, the message error stop now, but my problem  now is my array retuened from api, i look at noetwork and response status and the array is there, but idk why to pass to my listin my OnInit()

Answer (score 0):

double check what your service is returning. Most likely this:

```
this.subscriptions=res
```

Is not an array. And the most likely explanation for this is that you are returning a single record based on this.userid, instead of an array.

try to `console.log(this.subscriptions)` to see what it is. If it's not an array, you will get that error.

Comment: in console.log don't return nothing, not even errors

Comment: my problem  now is my array retuened from api, i look at noetwork and response status and the array is there, but idk why to pass to my listin my OnInit()